# itext, 2 different columns distribution on each page of a document pdf

Tags: java, pdf, datatable, itext

I had a request,

I have 2 text from different sources(text 1 and text 2), Inside the document I have to put one align to left and one to the right.I solved this part creating a cell of 2 columns with widths(70,30) and invisible borders.

Now I was asked to have a different distribution for each page, basically switching the columns, on the first page the cells are like cell1 on the left with 70%, and cell2 with 30%, but in page 2 I need to invert this and make cell2 on the left with 30%, and cell 1 on the right with 70%

please someone experienced on something similar, I am lost on this

Comment: Is each text continuing across multiple pages or do you have and add the text in a page-wise way?

Comment: Each text is independent, but for now I just find a way out by using the property of itext:  document.setMarginMirroring(true);